# How can I to use JSTL tags to insert a value of radio buttons into an Oracle database?

Tags: sql, oracle, jsp, jstl

How can I to use JSTL tags to insert a value of radio buttons into an Oracle database?

Comment: so what do you try ? please look into [ask] before posting here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you submit the html form with the radio buttons, in your servlet you have to extract radio buttons value, like:

```
public class ServletExample extends HttpServlet {
    ...
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)throws ServletException, IOException {       
        String radioValue1 = req.getParameter("radioValue1"); // here you have to pass the name or you radio button/group
        ...
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); // use your driver, here I use the mysql Driver
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String sql = String.format("INSERT INTO your_table(FIELD_FOR_RADIO_HERE,...) values(%s, ...) ", radioValue1);
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        ...
    }
}
```

This is the simplest way to insert data into your database, but for production environment you have to have a DAO tier that works with you database.